# Unity Photon Send data to server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to possible send data to server and save them there in Unity 5 and Photon?
for example send device UID, device Model, Device Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override *OnPhotonSerializeView* to write & read data.

```
void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info){
        if (stream.isWriting) {
            // Write device info
            stream.SendNext (deviceUID);
            stream.SendNext (deviceModel);
            stream.SendNext (deviceName);
        } else {
            // Read device info
            deviceUID = (string)stream.ReceiveNext ();
            deviceModel = (string)stream.ReceiveNext ();
            deviceName = (string)stream.ReceiveNext ();

        }
    }
```

The order of the variables you send should be in the same order you receive them. Your object also has to have a PhotonView attached to it.

You can see more info [here.](https://doc.photonengine.com/en/realtime/current/reference/serialization-in-photon)